# issue in jquery checkbox dropdown control

Tags: jquery

**strong text** i need to generate checkbox for  2 different data Table  in a  single drop down control

like
[alt text http://jdm8jq.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pBAyKOMS7Y7YbA6Q2kl5JA6RGHr3WCNh9aA1ttFzShAas36RQxTovGxkCqeMYfygADc5W8nmnPyONOCy9cOMGzAt3mR1ADyck/untitled.JPG](http://jdm8jq.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pBAyKOMS7Y7YbA6Q2kl5JA6RGHr3WCNh9aA1ttFzShAas36RQxTovGxkCqeMYfygADc5W8nmnPyONOCy9cOMGzAt3mR1ADyck/untitled.JPG)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/ui.dropdownchecklist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="../Scripts/ui.dropdownchecklist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Scripts/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.listBox').dropdownchecklist({maxDropHeight:200});
//$('.listBox').dropdownchecklist({ maxDropHeight: 200 }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>    <form id="form1" runat="server">    <div>   
     <asp:ListBox ID="listBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass ="listBox" />  
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClick="BtnClick" />    
          <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server" />  
            </div>  
              </form>
              </body>
</html>

 **in .cs**
```

i have  2  datatable in.cs  page

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); 
            ad.Fill(dt1);
            listBox.DataSource = dt1;
            listBox.DataBind();

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable(); 
            ad.Fill(dt2);
            listBox.DataSource = dt2;
            listBox.DataBind();
```

the site i am refering is [http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/demo.html][2]

how to  Bind 2 different tables under one control that is list box control.   so that i  can get two different data table  groups under one control
 one table  would  be an **items** table, and another table  could be  **itemsDetails** table. so that i have  show  2 differnet datatable details under  one control 
 what is the  syntax that i should follow  to get it  achived

hope my Question is clear

any help would be great

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure yet how to do it with 2 different binding sources but can't you just like loop through the datasets and add them manually?

Also your link does not work but I think this is the plugin your using right?

http://aleris.wordpress.com/2009/04/11/new-version-of-jquery-dropdown-checkbox-list-plugin/

If this is the right one they use "optgroup" what asp.net dropdown list does not seem to support. So that might be another problem your going to be facing and from what I saw from other people solving it you might have to override the drop down list control to add that.